# Local image displays well on the browser but not on my android device

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

the local image displays well on the browser but not display on my android device
 , the codes

```
<center><img class="image-full" width="200" src="../img/logo.png"></center>
```

this image displays well on my browser but not display on my android device (not found)

also if I exchanged the image source to online image like this (for example) "http://i.imgur.com/CC8zIPr.jpg"

it displays well on both browser and mobile

why this happens ??

index.html : http://pastebin.com/GEjS7Q54

login.html : http://pastebin.com/k5GXxfLS

app.js : http://pastebin.com/nLz6UFmD

Answer (score 0):

You can try using path without../

Change:

```
src="../img/logo.png"
```

To this:

```
src="img/logo.png"
```

Comment: No , it will not work
-- this will not path to my image

Comment: Ok , src="/android_asset/www/img/logo.png" worked for me .. 
but not worked in the browser
.. so I have to work with this path during development "/img/logo.png" ,, and then use this path "/android_asset/www/img/logo.png" during the deployment phase :))
I think - there's no another solution

Comment: same problem with ionic 2 , what to do ? @Federick Jones